# Do I need Java for Selenium testing?

Tags: java, selenium

Earlier this year, Oracle announced that it will drop support for Java SE 8 released after January 2019 to parties that don't own a commercial license:

> "**Public updates for Oracle Java SE 8 released after January 2019
>   will not be available for business, commercial or production use
>   without a commercial license.**

I am currently on a team that uses Selenium for testing our web application. I need to determine if the costs of the new commercial license will be worth it in the long term. Is there a different way we can continue testing our web application that doesn't use Java?

I've seen a lot of backlash over this move by Oracle, and know many people who are switching to OpenJDK, but I don't have the experience in making that decision and I would appreciate some answers or guidance.

Comment: Selenium has official bindings for about half-dozen languages, and unofficial for another half-dozen. Supposedly your Selenium **test** code is not released to customers, so switching to OpenJDK should not have any impact on the released software - why not just try it out?

Comment: @SiKing Yes the source code is for internal purposes only. But down the road there will be newer versions of Java that we won't be able to use unless we purchase the commercial license (according to my understanding), which is why maybe it is beneficial to look into OpenJDK?

Answer (score -1):

> Do I need Java for Selenium testing?
>
> No. Selenium has language bindings for many popular languages [Supported Platforms](https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp).
>   For example, Python.

There are a lot of resources for learning selenium in Python. 
You can start here [Python Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), or look here for some example codes [Python Selenium Examples](https://gist.github.com/hugs/830011)

Comment: I am aware that I can use a different programming language to build the tests using Selenium. But I think Selenium runs on a JVM so with this new licensing changes, we want to make sure we can continue to maintain our tests down the road. After next year we won't get Java updates unless we purchase a commercial license.